# how to apply multiple selectors?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, cycle

How can i write this javascript code in a loop ? I am using

```
$("#b1").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#a1").hide();
});
$("#b2").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#a2").hide();
});
$("#b3").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#a3").hide();
});
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `id` always ends with number, you could do like:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/);
}).click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to loop?  If you want same click function for multiple buttons/links use  **Class** selector instead of **ID**.

Example:

```
$(".classname").click(function ( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

At first, you can do

```
$("#a1, #a2, #a3, *etc*").click(function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Since that is rather 'ugly' in my opinion. I would try to add a class to the `#a1,2,3,4,etc.` elements. And put the class as selector.

```
$(".class_name").click(function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
});
```